# DIV element isn't placed correctly next to an image

Tags: html, css

So I'm questioning myself why the div with the class `champ_info` isn't placed next to the image because the image is an inline-block element. So the Text in my div element lies under the image instead of next to the image. My code is below.

```css
.champ_info {
  background: #0b2e33;
  color: white;
}

.champ_container {
  background: #10474e;
}

.champ_img {
  border: 3px solid #1ba9bd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 5rem;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="champ_container">
  <img class="champ_img" src="https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.5.1/img/champion/Pyke.png">
  <div class="champ_info">
    Some Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: because  div is a block element

Comment: But they are both in one div. I don't understand

Comment: this doesn't change the behavior of a *div* which will always take all the row even inside another div. You should probably put the text and the image inside the same div without wrapping the text inside a div

Comment: Your right but I need the div because I don't always want to display the div with this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div>` is a block element, which means it takes up the whole line. Put `display: inline;` inside the css for the `<div>` and it places it next to the image like you wanted.

Add `vertical-align: top;` if you want the text to align to the top. Since the image and the text align to the **bottom** of the parent, you need to manually set them to align to the top.

```css
.champ_info {
  background: #0b2e33;
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.champ_container {
  background: #10474e;
}

.champ_img {
  border: 3px solid #1ba9bd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 5rem;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="champ_container">
  <img class="champ_img" src="https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.5.1/img/champion/Pyke.png">
  <div class="champ_info">
    Some Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But now the Text is at the bottom how can I fix that? I want it to be at the top next to the image

Comment: @Pascal add `vertical-align: top;` to the image

Comment: @Pascal fixed it

Answer (score 3):

I personally find making inherently block level elements inline counter intuitive. Flex box is the perfect solution to your problem.

```css
.champ_container {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  align-items: center;
  background: #10474e;
}

.champ_info {
  background: #0b2e33;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.champ_img {
  border: 3px solid #1ba9bd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 5rem;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="champ_container">
  <img class="champ_img" src="https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.5.1/img/champion/Pyke.png">
  <div class="champ_info">
    Some Text
  </div>
</div>
```